# How can i update to spyder 5 on ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: python3, spyder

I did

```
conda update spyder
```

This does'nt seem to work.What else could I do?

Answer (score 2):

This is what worked for me:

First I removed spyder:

```
conda remove spyder
```

Then I installed spyder 5:

```
conda install spyder=5
```

For some reason, I had to put `spyder=5` when installing. Otherwise, I would only get `spyder 3`. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

Spyder 5 is not available even in the Ubuntu 21.10 development release because it was released on September 16, 2021, a few days before this question was posted, but it is available from the [official Spyder website](https://www.spyder-ide.org/) or it can be installed through the Anaconda distribution.

1. Update Anaconda distribution.

   ```
   conda update conda
   ```
2. Install Spyder 5 IDE.

   ```
   conda install -c anaconda spyder
   ```

   At the time this was written the above command installs Spyder 5.0.5.
3. Type `y` to proceed with the installation.
4. List spyder packages in the current environment.

   ```
   conda list spyder
   ```
5. When the installation is finished launch Spyder with the command `spyder`.

[The Anaconda Python Distribution (Linux)](https://dellwindowsreinstallationguide.com/python-installing-anaconda-linux/) webpage has information about advanced options for installing Spyder 5 in Linux.

---

**Spyder 5 core components** ([source](https://pypi.org/project/spyder/))

- Editor

  Work efficiently in a multi-language editor with a function/class browser, real-time code analysis tools (pyflakes, pylint, and pycodestyle), automatic code completion (jedi and rope), horizontal/vertical splitting, and go-to-definition.
- Interactive console

  Harness the power of as many IPython consoles as you like with full workspace and debugging support, all within the flexibility of a full GUI interface. Instantly run your code by line, cell, or file, and render plots right inline with the output or in interactive windows.
- Documentation viewer

  Render documentation in real-time with Sphinx for any class or function, whether external or user-created, from either the Editor or a Console.
- Variable explorer

  Inspect any variables, functions or objects created during your session. Editing and interaction is supported with many common types, including numeric/strings/bools, Python lists/tuples/dictionaries, dates/timedeltas, Numpy arrays, Pandas index/series/dataframes, PIL/Pillow images, and more.
- Development tools

  Examine your code with the static analyzer, trace its execution with the interactive debugger, and unleash its performance with the profiler. Keep things organized with project support and a built-in file explorer, and use find in files to search across entire projects with full regex support.

Answer (score 0):

To upgrade to another version, you simply pass the version desired.
For example, I want to upgrade to the latest version as when posting this, version 5.3.3, run the following commands in a terminal:

$ conda update anaconda

$ conda install spyder=5.3.3

Then launch with:

$ spyder